# Working with a pandas dataframe read from 'UTF-16' encoded csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unicode, utf-16

I'm working on a csv format dataset on python. This csv file looks like a normal csv file. When I tried to read it using pandas, it produced an error message saying

```
In: df = pandas.read_csv(filename)
Out: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid    start byte
```

Then I used `chardet` library and got to know the encoding of the file is `UTF-16`. I tried to read the file again as shown

```
df = pandas.read_csv(filename,encoding = 'UTF-16')
```

Now I was able to read the file. But When I tried to get its view using `df.head()` I got the output as shown below

```
In: df.head()
Out: Col1\tCol2\tCol3
     val1\tval2\tval3
```

all the columns got combined separated by `\`. How can I modify this csv file to make it work like a how typical utf-8 encoded csv file works?

> Edit:
> When I added `sep=None` in `pd.read_csv()` I was able to get the columns separated. Also, it took a bit long for `pd.read_csv()` to read the file when I added `sep=None` than when I just left the default value for `sep`.
> Can Somebody explain why these two things happened?

Comment: Have you tried ```df = pandas.read_csv(filename,encoding = 'UTF-16', sep="\")```  or  ```df = pandas.read_csv(filename,encoding = 'UTF-16', sep="\t")``` ?

Comment: Initially, I left the default value. Then I tried sep='\t'. It also didn't work. sep=None worked for me. But I don't know the reason it worked.